# Openvpn interupts WSL2

Tags: networking, openvpn, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I use WSL2 and vcXsrv to run some graphical Linux apps, namely emacs.
I configured vcXsrv to accept connections from remote clients.
I configured WSL2 to use DISPLAY `172.20.240.1:0`. This is the virtual network adaptor installed by WSL2.
This works perfectly with a very annoying problem. Which is whenever I use openvpn to connect to one of my clients, my Linux app loses connection to the X server. Then I'll have to kill the process and start it again.
Is there a way to let Openvpn **not** interrupt this connection?

Comment: I see this on my Linux virtual machines when I connect Sonic Wall Net Extender. If I do nothing, the connection in the Linux machine comes back after 5 - 10 seconds. Does your connection come back if you just wait a bit?

Comment: No. The application window just disappears. But if I check process list via `ps` I still see it in there. I don't think there's a `reconnect` mechanism in the X server world.

Comment: I am not sure. I will keep looking to see if I can find anything,

Comment: I found `https://xpra.org/` while researching this problem. Seems this app is specifically designed for this purpose, which kind of confirms that X by itself doesn't have a `reconnect` mechanism. But it looks to be more complicated than what I wish to do.

Comment: For what it may be worth, there were updates to Kali (what I am working in here) and today, use of Sonic Wall Net Extender plus mapping folders did not cause Kali to disconnect. You may try updating all your systems and apps.